# Message: An entity with the same identity already exists in this EntitySet

Tags: c#, wcf, entity, ria

I get the following error when adding an entity
"An entity with the same identity already exists in this EntitySet"
The frustrating part is that it is an intermittent issue and it is very hard for me to reproduce.
  My code:

```
     private void OKButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.IsHitTestVisible = false;
        Form Form = _context.Forms.FirstOrDefault();

        Form.Transactions.Add(new Transactions
        {
            Comments = textbox_taskcomments.Text,
            By = UserID,
            Name = Name,
            IssuedOn = DateTime.Now,
            StatusID = StatusID
        });

        this.DialogResult = DevExpress.Xpf.Core.DialogResult.OK;
        this.Close();
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated as I do not know where to start....

Thanks

Comment: Hey, just edited my answer provided a little more detail, regards

Comment: This error means that the entity you're trying to add already exists in the dbContext. Could you post up a little diagram of how your tables are structured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the [`contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335831.aspx) method?

> **Contains:** Specifies whether the EntitySet contains a specific entity.

You should be checking the contents of the `EntitySet` before you modify it.

```
 Transactions t = new Transactions{
        Comments = textbox_taskcomments.Text,
        By = UserID,
        Name = Name,
        IssuedOn = DateTime.Now,
        StatusID = StatusID
 };
 //check that the entity does not yet contain t
 if(!Form.Transactions.Contains(t)){
 //do something.
 }
```

(I don't know the rest of your code but.. from what I've [read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341748.aspx), this might be a solution)

Comment: Thanks Killrawr for the answer, but the thing is transactions are always unique...I cannot see anywhere in my code where i'm duplicating this entity in anyway:S

Comment: Good coding practice is to make logical statements to ensure these kind of errors don't occur anyway, does the error still occur even with the `contains` in place?. Kindest Regards